# Powershell, Converting SQLite SELECT-result to datatable, to JSON and JSON-export results in wrong JSON-file with special characters

Tags: json, powershell, sqlite

I'm using Powershell 7 and SQLite (System.Data.SQLite.dll) on WINDOWS 10.

This works fine:

- createing a SQLite-database and a SELECT-query
- converting the query-dataset to a datatable
- removing the columns added by SQLite (RowError, RowState, Table,
  ItemArray, HasErrors) from the datatable.

The resulting datatable displays fine in the console and is used for some converting-actions:

converting to a CSV-file works fine:

```
DbDataTable | Export-Csv -Path $myCsvFile -Delimiter $CsvDelimiter -UseQuotes 'AsNeeded' -NoTypeInformation
```

converting to JSon-Variable seems to work fine because Test-JSON returns true.

```
$DbDataJson = $DbDataTable | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -EscapeHandling Default

$validJson = $DbDataJson | Test-Json
write-host "valid Json" $validJson
$true
```

Outputting the JSON-variable works fine:

```
write-host $DbDataJson
```

displays the JSON-data as expected.

But writing the JSON-data to a file

```
$DbDataJson | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File $myJsonFile # -Encoding utf8
```

results in a file like this (excerpt), even with the parameter -Encoding utf8:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"FileID\": \"000009\",\r\n    \"SourceFile\": \"P:\\\\source\\\\DSCN0056.NEF\",\r\n    \"SourceFilePath\": \"P:\\\\source\",\r\n    \"
```

where FileID : 000009, SourceFile : P:\source\DSCN0056.NEF, SourcePath: P:\source ... is the expected JSON-dataset-result.

How can I get a proper JSON-output to a JSON-file?

Comment: Looks like `$DbDataJson` is already in Json format. So, just: `$DbDataJson | Out-File $myJsonFile`

Comment: Man, yes, works. Thank you so much. I have no idea, why I tried to convert JSON to JSON. All is fine now.